# How to take the first distinct (until the moment) elements of a list?

Tags: scala, collections

I am sure there is an elegant/funny way of doing it, 
but I can only think of a more or less complicated recursive solution.

Rephrasing:
Is there any standard lib (collections) method nor simple combination of them to take the **first distinct** elements of a list?

```
scala> val s = Seq(3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 7, 1, 2)
s: Seq[Int] = List(3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 7, 1, 2)

scala> s.takeWhileDistinct //Would return Seq(3,5,4,1), it should preserve the original order and ignore posterior occurrences of distinct values like 7 and 2.
```

Comment: @Vidya, added more concrete example.

Comment: The std lib could have a takeWhile applicable to all elements seen at the moment. However, the actual takeWhile is intended only to test on the very only element at the moment.

Comment: @flavian: Question was corrected. The example is right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want it to be fast-ish, then

```
{ val hs = scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int]()
  s.takeWhile{ hs.add } }
```

will do the trick.  (Extra braces prevent leaking the temp value `hs`.)

Comment: Computational cost is not a requirement, indeed it is fairly readable.

Comment: ...and very creative.

Comment: This is pretty damn neat.

Answer (score 2):

This is a short approach in a maximum of `O(2logN)`.

```
implicit class ListOps[T](val s: Seq[T]) {
    def takeWhileDistinct: Seq[T] = {
      s.indexWhere(x => { s.count(x==) > 1 }) match {
        case ind if (ind > 0) => s.take(
          s.indexWhere(x => { s.count(x==) > 1 }, ind + 1) + ind).distinct
        case _ => s
      }
    }
  }

val ex = Seq(3, 5, 4, 5, 7, 1)
val ex2 = Seq(3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 7, 1, 5) 

println(ex.takeWhileDistinct.mkString(", ")) // 3, 4, 5
println(ex2.takeWhileDistinct.mkString(", ")) // 3, 4, 5, 1
```

Look [**here**](http://scalafiddle.net/console/65699726a3c601b9f31bf04019c8593c) for live results.

Comment: Not so easy :). `val ex = Seq(3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 7, 1, 5)` should return 3,5,4,1, but returns 3,5,4

Comment: `val ex3 = Seq(3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 3, 7, 1, 5) //3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 3, 7, 1, 5`. There is already an answer, tnx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. Here's an alternative. First, let's get the stream of `s` so we can avoid unnecessary work (though the overhead is likely to be greater than the saved work, sadly).

```
val s = Seq(3, 5, 4, 5, 7, 1)
val ss = s.toStream
```

Now we can build s again, but keeping track of whether there are repetitions or not, and stopping at the first one:

```
val newS = ss.scanLeft(Seq[Int]() -> false) { 
  case ((seen, stop), current) => 
    if (stop || (seen contains current)) (seen, true) 
    else ((seen :+ current, false)) 
}
```

Now all that's left is take the last element without repetition, and drop the flag:

```
val noRepetitionsS = newS.takeWhile(!_._2).last._1
```

Comment: Seems correct, thanks. I will post an alternative I found now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simpler than the std lib function I was looking for (takeWhileConditionOverListOfAllAlreadyTraversedItems):

```
scala> val s = Seq(3, 5, 4, 1, 5, 7, 1, 2)
scala> s.zip(s.distinct).takeWhile{case(a,b)=>a==b}.map(_._1)
res20: Seq[Int] = List(3, 5, 4, 1)
```

Comment: Any help to turn it more idiomatic will be appreciated.

Comment: The takeWhileConditionOverAllAlreadyTraversedItems function deserves another Question in SO.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on Rex's (though I prefer his...)

This one is functional throughout, using the little-seen `scanLeft` method.

```
val prevs = xs.scanLeft(Set.empty[Int])(_ + _)
(xs zip prevs) takeWhile { case (x,prev) => !prev(x) } map {_._1}
```

UPDATE

And a lazy version (using iterators, for moar efficiency):

```
val prevs = xs.iterator.scanLeft(Set.empty[Int])(_ + _)
(prevs zip xs.iterator) takeWhile { case (prev,x) => !prev(x) } map {_._2}
```

Turn the resulting iterator back to a sequence if you want, but this'll also work nicely with iterators on both the input AND the output.